# calculate discount of prices in flutter

Tags: math, flutter, formula, percentage, discount

I want to try define below formula to calculate between old price and new price and show it on text widget but when i want to use it in an double variable i've got this error : "Only static members can be accessed in initializers"
and this is what i want to do:

```
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {
 final prod_fullName;
 final prod_pic;
 final prod_old_price;
 final prod_price;
 double percent=(prod_old_price - prod_price)/prod_old_price*100;
ProductDetails({
 this.prod_fullName,
 this.prod_pic,
 this.prod_old_price,
 this.prod_price,
});

@override
_ProductDetailsState createState() => _ProductDetailsState();
}
class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {
 Row{
  child:new Text("$percent%");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final String prod_fullName;
  final String prod_pic;
  final double prod_old_price;
  final double prod_price;

  const ProductDetails({Key key, this.prod_fullName, this.prod_pic, this.prod_old_price, this.prod_price}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductDetailsState createState() => _ProductDetailsState();
}
class _ProductDetailsState extends State<ProductDetails> {
  double percent;
  @override
  void initState() {
    percent=(widget.prod_old_price - widget.prod_price)/widget.prod_old_price*100;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("$percent%");
  }
}
```

Comment: dadash damet garm vali in khata ro mide :
Class 'String' has no instance method '-'.

Comment: @MehrdadHosseini. جواب ویرایش شد. دقت که که همه پارامترها الزامی اند

Comment: ممنونم ازت الان تستش می کنم

Comment: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
شما میدونی این خطا مربوط به چیه؟